# Is there any free (or cheap) software that can be used for testing WordPress functionality?

Tags: automation, scripts, testing

Is there any free (or cheap) software that can be used for testing WordPress functionality?

I would like to create some test scripts and then them against my self-hosted WordPress installation.

Comment: Related: [Best Practices for Regression Testing WordPress Websites?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4763/best-practices-for-regression-testing-wordpress-websites)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't really a WordPress question - more a generic web development issue.

These are some open source tools that can be used for scripting and testing a web browser session.

- [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/)
- [Cucumber](http://cukes.info/)
- [Watir](http://www.watir.com)